# Covering a MKMapView with an image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, overlay, mapkit

I want to create kind of a map view, just without the map..
Sound strange? I'll explain - I have a bunch of coordinates representing users location that I want to show on screen with there relative location from one another and from the user location (in center of the screen). But I don't want to show the map itself because I don't won't to expose the real address for privacy issues.

The map should look something like this:
[image: map]

I though of using the regular map kit so I have all of its functionality but I'm not sure how to do that. and I'm not sure if this is a violation of the google service license...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider to just ignore the mapkit and go with just location and images as pins. You can easily calculate where a person is standing in relation to another by just the longitude and latitude. it is not a violation of the terms as the gps from the iphone has nothing to do with google. Only the actual maps do.

(however if you are using google api related stuff without showing a map it might be a violation, for example you cannot query for altitude to google itself without showing a map. But then again the phone's gps gives you the altitude.)

Comment: but you dont really need a map per se right? you just want to be able to see the relative position regarding other people and a background image for example

Comment: Yes I don't really need the maps, It just seems easier to use a map and not calculate all the coordinates myself, no idea how to do that..

Answer (score 1):

Well, First of all it will be the violation of Google, as  `MKMapView` by default will query map tiles from Google server behind your hidden Overlay. So don't do that,

What I would suggest is to look into third party customize map solution for iOS. Something like MapBox.

See : [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-streets-ios-screencast/)

iOS SDK of MapBox : [SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/)

In which you can customize the color and look and feel of your Maps and location. There are paid option and free options too. Regarding the privacy issue I suggest you shoot an Email to MapBox people and ask if you can just hide the street names from the App.

Comment: Thanks but I rather not using third party maps, I'm hoping to find other ways to do that.

Comment: Any reason not to? Or it's just a matter of choice?